# Search not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql

Why won't my search function ever execute the "else" (else should echo a text when no resulsts haved been found)? I also have some problems when trying to show all results (with no search criterias selected, just by pressing the search button). I'll upload the whole code of the page because I don't know if you need the HTML part as well or not to figure out the problem. I know it's a big chunk of code but please help out if you can. Thanks!

Here's a link to my code: http://pastebin.com/BXe1C0dr

Comment: Paste it at other pasting site. For example: http://www.pastebin.com

Comment: sorry for the site where I uploaded the code... I tried on more popular upload sites and it wouldn't let me because it's .php

Comment: @MateiPanchios - no offence but your code is really difficult to make sense of. Are you getting any errors in your php log?

Comment: No, no errors. Yeah, I figured it out it will be hard for you to read it since it has a bunch of romanian words and comments. It just won't execute the else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet the answer, just a brief code structure of Matei Panchios code. Because it is hard to make sense of long code, so I try to simplify it so that other people might be able to help.

```
$termeni = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['termeni']);
$tip=$_POST['tip'];
$judet=$_POST['judet'];

if((!empty($termeni)) and (isset($tip))  and (isset($judet))) {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM oferte WHERE localitate LIKE '%$termeni%' AND 
              tip_locatie='$tip' AND judet='$judet'";
     // do the query and write some HTML
} elseif (isset($tip)) {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM oferte WHERE tip_locatie='$tip'";
     // do the query and write some HTML
} elseif (isset($judet)) {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM oferte WHERE judet='$judet'";
     // do the query and write some HTML
} elseif (!empty($termeni)) {
    ...
} elseif (!empty($termeni) AND (isset($judet))) {
    ...
} elseif (!empty($termeni) AND (isset($tip))) { 
    ...
} elseif ((isset($judet)) AND (isset($tip))) {
    ...
} elseif ((!isset($judet)) AND (!isset($tip)) AND (empty($termeni))) {
    ...
}  else {
    // I believe this where it does not get executed.
}
```

Well, it makes sense why it does not get executed because there is other way that the `elseif` does not cover. If you look from this point of view

- If three variable is set

> ```
> if((!empty($termeni)) and (isset($tip))  and (isset($judet))) {
> ```

- If two variables is set

> ```
> elseif (!empty($termeni) AND (isset($judet)))
> elseif (!empty($termeni) AND (isset($tip)))
> elseif (!empty($termeni) AND (isset($tip)))
> elseif (!empty($termeni) AND (isset($tip)))
> ```

- If one variable is set

> ```
> elseif (isset($tip))
> elseif (isset($judet))
> elseif (!empty($termeni))
> ```

- When no variable is set

> ```
> elseif ((!isset($judet)) AND (!isset($tip)) AND (empty($termeni)))
> ```

- which leave `else` condition with nothing to cover.

---

If I were you, I would structure the code as following.

```
if (!empty($termeni) and isset($tip)  and isset($judet)) {
    query = '....';
} elseif (!empty($termeni) and isset($judet) {
    query = '....';
} // .... the rest of the condition

$result =  mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // write HTML table
} else {
   // write message that there is no result found
}
```

This will reduce the size of your code by 6 times.

Comment: Indeed, that is the "else" I was talking about, thanks for taking the time to figure things out and help the others! :)

Comment: Basically what I want that else to do is to display a message saying that no result could be found. So if any of the conditions that you mentioned get executed and don't return results then this else should execute and echo the message.

Comment: Updated my answer. I advise you to re-structure your code for more readability and to achieve your goal in elegant way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I'll try to re-structure the code, I think it will work this way. Sorry for the headache of having to read 400 rows of code. Thanks again!

Comment: It's okay. I just do a brief scanning, not read the code entirely.